# What to do when a Linux account gets owned?

Tags: intrusion, investigation

What is the best course of action when you discover that a non-administrator Linux account has gotten owned, and a single foreign process is running, making all sorts of networking connections?

For example, how would one take a complete snapshot of the process for future analysis?

Take into consideration that the executable itself might have been deleted, so, even the binary itself you'd have to [find through an inode with something like debugfs](https://superuser.com/a/629440/180573), but there's also the question of preserving other evidence.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the root account has not been compromised (and this is *not* a good assumption -- the attacker may have used a privilege escalation attack without leaving traces), you can trust the log files and the system utilities.  In this case, I'd dump the program memory for analysis (eg. by triggering a [core dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump)), archive the user's files and the temporary directories, and then wipe the user's account and files and restore from backup.

The technical details are better suited for a site such as [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).